# How to enable/disable 3rd party apps in Android?

Tags: android

As It is well known, from Android Ice Cream Sandwich (version 4.0) we can disable or enable system's built-in apps. Now, I want to develop an Android application in which I want to add this feature in system's setting for 3rd party applications also. Is this possible to do it programmatically ?

Any help would be appreciable.

How to disable system apps in Android Ice Cream Sandwich

1. Go into the main system settings. (You can get there by selecting the "Settings" icon within your phone's app tray.)
2. Scroll down to the "Device" section and select the "Apps" option.
3. Tap the tab at the top that's labeled "All," then scroll through the list to find the app you wants to blast.
4. Tap on the app, then tap the "Disable" button. Tap "OK" on the confirmation box that appears.

After those steps, you can successfully disable the system apps. If nothing happen, just restart your phone.

Comment: "Is this possible to do it programmatically ?" -- no, except maybe on a rooted device.

Comment: If I want to do it for rooted device, so can you please provide me some useful links ?

Comment: No. I know that it is not part of the Android SDK, and it is generally possible for somebody with root privileges to do pretty much anything. Beyond that, I cannot help you.

Comment: Okay, then I am moving to XDA Developers. Thanks Mark L. Murphy.

Comment: Why not look at the source for your stock Settings app? It should tell you *exactly* how to do it.

Comment: Uh, I came across the same requirement and need to find some sort of solution. The advantage is we own the hardware and can modify the firmware per our requirement. Can anyone suggest if I can achieve this via firmware or modifying the framework apps.